# Android: Playing Music Off SD Card

Tags: android, media-player, android-sdcard

I want to play a mp3 file off the SD card of my android emulator but I am having trouble. How do you put a file on the emulator's SD card? Also how do I format the path to a file on the SD card?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

If you go the the DDMS view in android (whilst your emulator is running).

Select the 'File Explorer' tab and you can see all the files within that sdcard.img file.

*ensure* you have created an emulator with an SD card attached

Reference:

[Another user asking similar but diff Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974401/where-is-data-data)